# Rvest to scrape Linkedin profile

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using Rvest to scrape my linkedin profile.
But I am stuck at experience section.
below xpath is used to scape the experience section but it returns 0 nodeset

Test<-read %>%
html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="experience-section"]')

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hello instead of scraping you can use their [API](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/)